# The total number of solar eclipses in a century repeats roughly every 6th century

Tags: the-sun, orbit, solar-eclipse

We know that on a longer time scale (millions of years) the orbits of planes are unstable and it is impossible to make predictions about eclipses millions of years into the future. But on a shorter scale, the behaviour of orbits can be considered to be fairly stable. I was studding the distribution of the number of solar eclipses in short time scale (thousands of years as opposed to millions of years)

[NASA has published the list of the count of solar eclipses](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEcat5/SEcatalog.html) (total + annular  + partial) every century from 1999 BC to 3000 AD. When we plot count of eclipses against the century (-19 for 1999 BC to 1900 BC, +30 for 2900 AD to 3000 AD) we get a curve which roughly looks like a sine wave. I fitted a sine curve on this data and obtained a good fit with $R^2 = 0.9$. Since a sine function is period function with a period of $2\pi$ it means that the number of solar eclipses in a century should roughly repeat every $2\pi$ century or 6th century (6.28th century to be precise). Example: For the 6 century cycle starting from the first century AD we have (1AD, 248), (7AD, 251), (13AD, 246), (19AD, 242) etc. Generalising this, for any time period $T$ instead a century, we have the hypothesis:

**Hypothesis**:

*The number of solar eclipses in a time interval of length $T$ has a quasi-period of $2\pi T$.*

**Question**: Is it possible to provide a theoretical justification to this empirically observed trend? I am more interested in why should the quasi-period be $2\pi T$ rather than just why there should be a quasi-period.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Saros Cycle?

Comment: That's quite interesting. NASA has also published the solar eclipses by date. Have you analysed that data to validate the hypothesis? And what are the residuals on the $R^2$ fit?

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/418408/2451

Answer (score 2):

From the same [NASA page](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEcat5/SEcatalog.html):

> The recurrence of solar eclipses is governed by the [Saros](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEsaros/SEsaros.html) cycle. For more information, see [Periodicity of Solar Eclipses](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEsaros/SEperiodicity.html).

which then goes on to say:

> The periodicity and recurrence of eclipses is governed by the Saros cycle, a period of approximately 6,585.3 days (18 years 11 days 8 hours). It was known to the Chaldeans as a period when lunar eclipses seem to repeat themselves, but the cycle is applicable to solar eclipses as well.